# Reference Windows Form Project From another Windows Form Project in same Solution

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inheritance, reference

I have a solution with several projects most of which are code or control libraries.  I have a main windows forms application that references and uses these libraries.  What i am trying to do is create a 2nd windows application that extends the main one, but i would like to be able to deploy them as separate exe's.

When i try to add a reference to the new app referencing the main app; all seems fine until i try to run the new app i get several error msgs similar to below:

```
Error   1   Could not find file 'ADODB.dll' referenced by assembly 'D:\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\X\XX\bin\Debug\XXX.exe.manifest'.    <newAppName>
```

i have tried adding references to all the dll's in the error messages and they are still listed when i try to run the new app.  I thought of a few work arounds but they require user changes to maintain separate exe's at deployment. I would like to avoid this if possible.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found a reasonable work around.  Basically you add all the reused forms as existing items, but instead of just clicking add you click the drop down arrow and choose add as link.

It would be great to redesign as JTew suggested above but this gets me where i need to be without having to move code.

You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92.aspx)

Thanks for all your time looking this over and hopefully is helpful to more

Jeff Spo

Answer (score 0):

Your windows forms applications should not be the point that you extend, the exe files should really just be a shell for launching your process (as much as possible anyways). So this response doesn't answer your specific problem of reference exes as this is not considered good practice.

All the extensions should be made to your code or control libraries off a known interface or contract. Generally the process for extending applications like this is to use alternate or additional DLLs which are loaded at runtime.

Say you have an application called clock which is to display the time.

You can structure your application with a set of contracts (or interfaces) in a referenceable DLL "Clock.Contracts.dll":

```
public interface ITimeService
{
public string Name { get; }
public Date GetTime();
}
```

You then have each implementation of this in another DLL ("Clock.LocalComputer.dll", "Clock.InternetTime.dll"

```
public class LocalTime : ITimeService
{
public string Name
{ get { return "Local Time"; }}
public Date GetTime()
{ return Date.Now; }
}
```

In the UI/EXE you always reference the interface don't call the implementation.

How do you get an instance of the implementing class, using Reflection to identify if a class in a DLL implements the interface and Activator.CreateInstance to generate the class.

http://gsraj.tripod.com/dotnet/reflection.html

There are patterns like Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection which help to address these things in a standardized way in your application. 3rd party libraries like Castle Windsor, Spring can assist. A google search on these will give you some reading material.

I will say that it can take a while to fully get your head around these things.

Comment: i agree but the original exe is some 30k lines of code and there is too much risk moving all that code around at this point. So i need to figure out a work around with the structure as is. I will def use your reading suggestion though.  Thanks for your input.